# How to uncheck a checked asp:CheckBox when another is checked in an asp:GridView

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox, aspxgridview

I have an asp:CheckBox column in an asp:GridView. I am trying to uncheck previously checked CheckBox when another one is checked using javascript.
I have seen code dealing with 2 checkboxes but not in an asp:gridview.
I am new to javascript so any help would be appreciated.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewGroups" runat="server" >
   <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField>
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow2" class="icheckbox" runat="server" />                                                                                                                                 
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>                                                                                
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: So you want your check box to act as a radio button? Only have one selected at a time?

Comment: Use a radio button not checkbox if you only want one selected at a time - people can always turn off js so doing it with js can lead to bad data unless you also write something into your server side validation

Comment: I ended up handling it on the server side.